# VBA extract values from variable range in multiple worksheet file

Tags: excel, vba, range, userform

[Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEG77.jpg)

I am still learning VBA and I understand that the major challenge of posing a question here on stackoverflow is be clear in the objective and thinking process. Let's see if I can make the point clear.

I am facing files with multiple worksheets which have the following peculiarities:

- Time series data, which may come organized with line items in rows and years the columns or vice versa, don't have a fixed range.
- Each time series may have different names for the same item across different files (say Revenues, Rev, XYZ Reven, etc).

I would like to create a tool that let the user select specific time series and  stores data in a collection or array for calculations (say the average of the time series) in a new workbook.

First approach I tried was to adapt a code I've found from J.Walkenbackh on mapping a file ([https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/using-vba-to-create-a-worksheet-map/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEG77.jpg)) but I have not found a clear strategy to deal with text cells that may also belong to numeric data due to poor formatting at the source file. Below is my partial attempt to get the cells that are text files.

I think I am getting confused on the approach I should take here and I have also complicated the matter trying to use classes to map time series with standard names.

Hope I made my point clear and would appreciate your help. Thanks!

```
    Sub QuickMap()
  Dim FormulaCells As Variant
  Dim TextCells As Variant
  Dim NumberCells As Variant
  Dim Area As Range
  Dim cel As Range
  Dim coll As New Collection

  If TypeName(ActiveSheet) <> "Worksheet" Then Exit Sub
'  Create object variables for cell subsets
  On Error Resume Next
  Set FormulaCells = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlNumbers + xlTextValues + xlLogical)
  Set TextCells = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues)
  Set NumberCells = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers)
  On Error GoTo 0

'  Add a new sheet and format it
  Sheets.Add
  With Cells
    .ColumnWidth = 2
    .Font.Size = 8
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'  Do the formula cells
  If Not IsEmpty(FormulaCells) Then
    For Each Area In FormulaCells.Areas
      With ActiveSheet.Range(Area.Address)
        .Value = "F"
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      End With
    Next Area
  End If

'  Do the text cells
  If Not IsEmpty(TextCells) Then
    For Each Area In TextCells.Areas
      With ActiveSheet.Range(Area.Address)
        .Value = "T"
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
      End With
    Next Area
  End If

'  Do the numeric cells
  If Not IsEmpty(NumberCells) Then
    For Each Area In NumberCells.Areas
      With ActiveSheet.Range(Area.Address)
        .Value = "N"
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
      End With
    Next Area
  End If

  'Check if range is vertical(?)

  'Loop through each cell of the area
   For Each Area In TextCells.Areas
    For Each cel In Area
        If cel.Value <> vbNullString Then
             coll.Add cel.Value, cel.Address
        End If
    Next cel
   Next Area

b_frmSelect.List1.list = coll
b_frmSelect.Show
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you're looking for a way to check if the value of a cell is text? In this case, you could try the IsNumeric method which will return False if the value of the cell can't be cast to a number.

Comment: Best way to let us help you is to post some examples of how you currently have the data, how do you want it to be and the description of the steps to transform it.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, I have added a data sample on top of the question but what the source file may present could be anything with items in columns and years in rows and very unpredictable formats and positioning. I want to give the user the ability to select items and store the data series in an array or collection for other uses including charting. Hope this clarified but let me know if I should make it more clear. I shall very much appreciate any help!